# ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-routing

I am trying to add or remove nested has_many object as follows

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
end

= form_for @question, :url => {:action => "create"} do |f|
  = f.label :name
  = f.text_field :name
  #comments
  = link_to 'Add Comment", add_comment_question_path, method: :get
  = f.submit
```

:javascript

```
  $('#add_comment').click(function() {
    $('#comments').append("#{escape_javascript(render(:partial => "comment"))}");
  });
```

In my _comment.html.haml

```
= fields_for @question.comments do |c|
  = c.label :msg
  = c.text_field :msg
```

In my controller

```
def add_comment
   @question.comments << Comment.new
end
```

In routes.rb

```
resources :questions do
  get :add_comment, :on => :member
end
```

But I am getting routing error on loading `question/new.html.haml`. I also ran `rake routes` getting the correct specified url. why I am getting this error?

Comment: can you edit the html code of your question?

Comment: specify the routing error that you are getting. No route matches what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'm assuming the error is in `add_comment_question_path`.  This named route requires a question resource to passed to it like `add_comment_question_path(@question)`.  But this will still not work in your case since you are trying to create `@question` in the same form.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
= form_for @question, :url => questions_path do |f|
```

`questions_path` should be automatically generated from `routes.rb`. These can be enumerated by running `rake routes`, which shows available routes that can then be evoked either with `route_path` or `route_url`.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Try to add method to post:

```
form_for(@question, :url => {:action => "create"}, :html => {:method => "post"} ) do |f|
```

And edit routes.rb as:

**In routes.rb**

```
resources :questions do
   member do
     get :add_comment
   end
end
```